# Why does getPlugin method in Cmds.java not work?

Tags: java, bukkit

i want to change from **EventsClass.class** the *logged* variable which is 
placed in **Cmds.class**.

But i have a problem with this line:

```
private EventsClass plugin = EventsClass.getPlugin(EventsClass.class);
```

Compiler cannot resolve getPlugin.

**CODE**:

*Main.java:*

```
package com.github.noisersup.serverrust.LoginMe;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        loadConfig();
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new EventsClass(),this);
    }

    public void loadConfig(){
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        this.saveConfig();
    }
}
```

*EventsClass.java:*

```
    package com.github.noisersup.serverrust.LoginMe;

    import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
    import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
    import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
    import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
    import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;

    import java.util.UUID;

    public class EventsClass implements Listener {

    public boolean logged;

    @EventHandler
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){

        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        UUID uuid = p.getUniqueId();

        logged = false;

        if("player."+uuid+".password"!=null){

            //login
            p.sendMessage("§2Welcome again "+p.getName()+"! Please login with command: §6§n/login <password>");


        }else{
            //register
            p.sendMessage("§2Welcome "+p.getName()+"! Please register with command: + §6§n/register <password> <repeat_password>");
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent e){
        if(!logged){
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }

    }
}
```

*Cmds.java:*

```
package com.github.noisersup.serverrust.LoginMe;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;


import java.util.UUID;

public class Cmds implements CommandExecutor {


    String cmd1 = "login";
    String cmd2 = "register";
    String cmd3 = "changepassword";

    private EventsClass plugin = EventsClass.getPlugin(EventsClass.class);


    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String s, String[] args) {

        if(sender instanceof  Player) {
            Player p = (Player) sender;
            UUID uuid = p.getUniqueId();

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cmd1)) {
                if ("player." + uuid + ".password" != null){
                    if(!args[0].isEmpty()) {
                        if (args[0].equals("player." + uuid + ".password")) {
                            p.sendMessage("§2Logged!");
                            logged = true;
                        }else{
                            p.sendMessage("§4Wrong password!");
                        }
                    }else{
                        p.sendMessage("§4Enter password!");
                    }
                }else{
                    p.sendMessage("§4You must be registered before login.");
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler cannot resolve `getPlugin(...)` method because there's no such method in `EventsClass`. It has only the methods `onJoin(...)` and `onMove(...)`.

Comment: @haba713 ok, but when you use `getplugin()` with Main class it is work without method declaration

Comment: That's because `Main` extends `JavaPlugin` which has [such a method](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.html#getPlugin(java.lang.Class)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will clearly indicate a compilation error:

```
private EventsClass plugin = EventsClass.getPlugin(EventsClass.class);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

because there's no `getPlugin(Class<?> class)` defined in `EventsClass` class.

`EventsClass` only define `onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e)` and `onMove(PlayerMoveEvent e)` methods.

On the other hand `Main` class here is extending `JavaPlugin` with the following method:

```
public static <T extends JavaPlugin> T getPlugin(Class<T> clazz)
```

This is why a `Main.getPlugin(...)` call might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler cannot resolve the method `getPlugin(...)` becuase `EventsClass` has no such a method it.  It has only the methods `onJoin(...)` and `onMove(...)`.